# Async Task /w Connection\Server Availability

Tags: java, android

What is the proper way of doing this?  I see a lot of suggestions to use Connectivity Manager but that will only determine the client side connection.  What if the server is down?

Also what kind of exception would I catch to process the error message

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Http , you will Transport Exceptions.
Actual exception depends on the Http Client being used for communication. It will be an IOException in most of the cases

[URLConnection#connect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29)

Comment: I was trying to modify the Layout from inside the Async doinBackground task, I used to IOException to set a boolean and then a post test on the PostProcess task to check the results.